# Blender 3.6 does not react at all to the auto normalize option

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

Blender 3.6 does not react at all to the auto normalize option, the skin weight softening brush works very poorly. Mirror coloring of the weight of symmetrical bones is turned on extremely rarely, according to a completely incomprehensible logic. It's a shame that such a wonderfully designed software creates such hellish problems in skin weight coloring. After all, this is a fundamental thing.

---

I looked last night at several options for enabling auto weight normalization (from 2 to 1 units), but I could not extend it to the entire model. The option works only for separately selected vertices.

Please provide instructions to overcome this problem.

---

Of the nuances that can be said for reference. I have an insect model. The dimensions of the model are 30 meters. When searching for a problem, I met the opinion that the problem is with small-sized models. I used various tricks as a solution: I connected duplicate points by distance, and increased and reduced the rig by 10 times, then removed the parent and rejoined the empty groups. I don't understand what else can be done.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Voting to close on that basis.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker. Maybe I expressed myself incorrectly. The question is how to enable auto normalization when skinning. I included it in the brush options in the tools. And in the weight options. Normalize or normalize everything. When checking the vertices after these operations, vertices still had 2 units of influence. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Even then, I'd be voting to close on the basis of not enough information.  Autonormalization depends on context (like locked groups, modifiers) and doesn't work with all tools (like gradients.)  We may be able to explain how to achieve the specific weights you want, hopefully most easily, given a specific goal; we may be able to answer why Blender gives the output it does, given a * rigorously detailed* procedure and a file to follow along with.  Either of those would be valid questions for BSE in my opinion.

Comment: Auto normalization does not work with normal bone and mesh placement. No modifier other than Armature is involved. With a selected bone, any part of the grid where there is no weight is blue, where there is weight it is red. But in the red area, the influence of other bones is also added and the sum of their influence is 2. The autonormalization option does not react at all in the context of the brush menu. Not to the viewport menu contest where the is weight and going into it there are commands: normalize everything, normalize.

Comment: I don't know the local rules for posting links to a file. Just in case, I'll post it in the next post. In YouTube, for example, such messages are erased. https://disk.yandex.ru/d/VNNJrEp85pgfqw https://disk.yandex.ru/d/VNNJrEp85pgfqw

Comment: Files are encouraged.  I recommend hosting on https://blend-exchange.com/ .  I personally cannot follow what you're doing from the steps you listed, but I could show you, with a file, how to get normalized weights, either from painting or from the "normalize all" operation (possibly, some combination of the two,) given starting weights.

Comment: The "auto-normalize" only affects the brush while you paint. If you need to normalize already existing weights, you have a few "normalize" operators available under the "weights" menu if I remember correctly.

Comment: i added the file. I really want to understand what's going on. I'm a Blender fanatic but am now forced to do this task in Maya due to a problem. File link [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vNPlBOmS" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vNPlBOmS/)

Comment: L0Lock I think I have tried all available options. Bone influence has 2 units. In Maya, I have now done in 2 hours what I could not do in Blender for 1.5 days. This is a sad moment, since I have all the plans with Blender, I have already made several cartoons in it. Please look at the file and if it's not difficult give me a couple of instructions on how to fix the skin of the body.

Comment: I'm away fro home right now, will check later today.

Comment: L0Lock, Thank you very much for your participation! I'll already complete the task in Maya, but I need to know how to do it in Blender for the future. Please take your time and check it out at your convenience.

Comment: Hi, @MrGravicaper, While sympathizing with your frustration, I think it would be easier for folks to help you, and better suited to our format, if you restricted yourself to one issue at a time. There are several mentioned in your question, You're welcome to ask about each, separately. If you isolate the problems, and present them with the simplest examples you can construct, preferably illustrated, you'll attract better, more accurate answers.  You may want to improve / alter my  edit. (This comment exchange may get moved to a chat-room if it gets too long.)

Comment: Robin Betts, Excuse me, please. There was a very very urgent task (I've already completed it in Maya) and I wanted to get as much information as possible quickly. For the future I understood your comment, 1 problem = 1 question. This message of mine can also be reduced to one question. How to make auto weight normalization work. In Maya, this is not a problem, and I quickly completed the skin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Area of effect

Normalization acts only on vertex groups from a deform bone since they are the only one that need normalization and you might have other groups doing other things you don't want to mess up.

Your Spine bone isn't marked as a Deform bone, so any normalization operation will ignore that bone's vertex group.

[image]

All bones are marked as Deform by default, only bones like mechanical or controllers should be unmarked. Make a pass on your rig to check all bones deform states.

When does normalization operate

#### When painting

The "auto-normalize" is an option of the weight paint brush, the only time it will normalize is when you paint something, and it also needs Multi-paint enabled to be able to impact other vertex groups and not the current painted one:

[image]

But again: this will only affect the action of painting.

### Normalizing existing weights

To fix weights that are already made:

1. Make sure all the vertex groups are unlocked:
   [image]
2. If you have any of the face or vertex selection masking enabled, disable them or select all your mesh with <kbd>A</kbd> (Blender basically always acts on selection only):
   [image]
3. Optionally select a vertex group you would rather preserve if you have one
4. Use the menu Weights Normalize to normalize the current vertex group from the other groups. Or Normalize All to normalize all vertex groups:
   [image]
5. If there's no group you want to preserve from normalization, hit <kbd>F9</kbd> to get the last operator options, and disable "Lock Active"

Comment: L0Lock, Thank you so much for such detailed instructions! Civilization rests on people like you. I promise that the time spent on me will not be in vain. Thanks to you, I will make my cartoons in this wonderful Blender program. Can you please tell me what needs to be done to finish the topic? It seems like the last time my issue was resolved, I had to click on some button or checkbox. My English is bad, I use a translator and I'm afraid to seem ungrateful by clicking on the wrong button. As far as I understand a good answer increases the rating of the one who advises. Sincerely.

Comment: My answer says it all.